# problems with the build.xml

Tags: ant

well, i don´t understand this problem because i defined the attribute src.dir and when i compiled the project,show me this message.

```
C:\Archivos de programa\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\branch_try_htmlModulo2\build.xml:71: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

somebody help me please, i need to fix this error

check it, http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=lppl5lbscbas4qe&thumb=4

Comment: i don´t know how to fix this error, i want to use a src, this src is another folder, then, i want to know if i can  use this source

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a standard compile failure rather than anything specifically wrong with the build.xml.

Your class `ProductDAO` references a package (`flex.messaging.io`) that either does not exist or that is not available on the classpath.

Check to see whether the appropriate JAR file is included by `master-classpath`.

Comment: thanks you, i incluided the JAR file but now. i compile and run the project and show me this message                      

Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.WelcomeController] for bean with name '/welcome.htm' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/branch_try_htmlModulo-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.WelcomeController
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.WelcomeController

Comment: check it, this is link of the image of project   


http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=pmhqbdsu3u8z0nv&thumb=4

Comment: i can´t fix this error

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.WelcomeController] for bean with name '/welcome.htm' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/branch_try_htmlModulo-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.WelcomeController

in the build.xml set the attribute src.dir :  <property name="src.dir" value="${backend.dir}/java-src/catw/src"/>

I want to know if I'm doing something wrong. I need help, please